# npm ERR! fibers@3.1.1 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Similar questions here did not help me.

I am installing a react project downloaded from github, and I am stuck at installing the very first package: npm install axios

I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fibers@3.1.1 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@3.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Other answers here all said it was a problem with the nodejs version, so I downloaded the newest version and installed it (on my windows 8.1). Nodejs is now at version 15.5.0. I also updated npm to the newest 6.14.10 version, force cleaned cache, rebooted, but I still get the same error.

Very thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Would you be able to share the repo ?

Comment: Sure, this is it: https://github.com/jeffersonRibeiro/react-shopping-cart

Comment: are you trying to install `axios` package globally? or did you experience the issue when running `npm install` within the repository you shared?

Comment: I usually install each package one by one (from within the local project path) instead of doing npm install because I have a slow internet connection and in case it fails at some point I need to know which packages were succeffully installed and which still haven't - so I do it one by one instead. So yes, I was doing 'npm install axios' and got that error.